# Python - How can I download csv dataset from ourworldindata.org in Google Colab?

Tags: python, download, google-colaboratory

As written in the question, I would like to download a csv dataset from the website [ourworldindata.org](https://ourworldindata.org/) for further data manipulation using Google Colab. In principle, I could download it to my machine and upload it to Colab or save it to my Google Drive after having linked it to the Colab worksheet.
However, I was wondering if there is a more straightforward way to get the data.

Comment: Hi Lorenzo, welcome. Please review our edit suggestions to your question

Answer (score 0):

You can download datasets using `!wget 'link to the file'`, but in ourworldindata.org, you don't get a specific link to download the .csv file is what I observed in most of the cases.

But for a few datasets, you can find the link to download the .csv file and you can use

```
cd 'working_folder'

!wget https://covid.ourworldindata.org/data/owid-covid-data.csv
```

to download the file directly to your working folder